# How to read from one DB but write to another using Snowflake's Snowpark?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowpark

I'm SUPER new to Snowflake and Snowpark, but I do have respectable SQL and Python experience. I'm trying to use Snowpark to do my data prep and eventually use it in a data science model. However, I cannot write to the database from which I'm pulling from -- I need to create all tables in a second DB.

I've created code blocks to represent both input and output DBs in their own sessions, but I'm not sure that's helpful, since I have to be in the first session in order to even get the data.

I use code similar to the following to create a new table while in the session for the "input" DB:

```
my_table= session.table("<SCHEMA>.<TABLE_NAME>")
my_table.toPandas()

table_info = my_table.select(col("<col_name1>"),
                             col("<col_name2>"),
                             col("<col_name3>").alias("<new_name>"),
                             col("<col_name4"),
                             col("<col_name5")             
                            )


table_info.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('MAINTABLE')
```

I need to save the table MAINTABLE to a secondary database that is different from the one where the data was pulled from. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to provide fully qualified name:

```
table_info.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.MAINTABLE')
```

[DataFrameWriter.save_as_table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/_autosummary/snowflake.snowpark.html#snowflake.snowpark.DataFrameWriter.save_as_table)

> Parameters:
>
> table_name – A string or list of strings that specify the table name or fully-qualified object identifier (database name, schema name, and table name).

Comment: Will there be any issues in performing this with the second DB while utilizing a session associated with the different DB?

Comment: @drymolasses If the role used for connection have access to both DB there shouldnot be any issues